# wireless display for MAC

Tags: display, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have a MAC and I am looking to add two additional displays to my laptop without having to run cables to it.  Is there an app or something I can install on my Raspberry pi to be able to use it as a wireless display for the MAC?

Comment: what do you want to display?

Comment: I want to use it as an additional display for my MAC.